# Phoenix router scope issue

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, router

How could I do that i send a GET request to api/events and I get public events only but if i send an auth token then i get the user’s events?
Basically using the same route but returning something different if there is a user logged in.
I believe it has to do something with the router, if I send just to /api scope it won’t have a user ever, but if I send to [:api, :jwt_authenticated] without a token then it obviously says that I am not logged in.
I tried to make a separate definition for returning if not logged in, but same result

```
  scope "/api", DotooAppWeb do
pipe_through(:api)
get("/users", UserController, :index_not_logged)
post("/users", UserController, :create)
get("/events", EventController, :index_not_logged)

scope "/auth" do
  post("/identity/callback", AuthenticationController, :identity_callback)
end

pipe_through(:jwt_authenticated)

resources("/users", UserController, only: [:index, :create, :show, :update, :delete])
resources("/events", EventController, only: [:index, :create, :show, :update, :delete])
end
```

Is there a way around this?
I followed this article mainly for setting up my authentication: http://blog.nathansplace.co.uk/2018/ueberauth-and-guardian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this should happen in the Router, although you could technically make it work.

If your motivation is to separate the logic for both these cases, you could have the `UserController.index` function just check whether the user is logged in, then delegate to functions that fetch public / user-specific events. It also has the advantage of being very transparent because all the logic that determines what the endpoint returns is in one single place.

Hope that helps!